# Solitaire Game- Stacking Cards on one another

Tags: javascript, html, css

Below is my code where i wanna place(stack) cards on div ..but only first card gets place as -20px other all are placed as 0px..position ....how to solve it ?? :(
function myFunction() {
            for(j=1;j<8;j++){

```
            for(i=1;i<7;i++){
                if(j<2){
                var x = document.createElement("IMG");
                x.setAttribute("src", "AllCards/cvr.png");
                x.setAttribute("id", "r"+j);
                x.setAttribute("width", "auto");
                x.setAttribute("height", "auto");
                x.setAttribute("alt", "one");
                document.getElementById("c"+i).appendChild(x);
                alert("r"+j+" c"+i);

                //document.getElementById("r"+j).style.position = "relative";
                //document.getElementById("r"+j).style.top="20px";

                }
                else if(j<3){
                var x = document.createElement("IMG");
                x.setAttribute("src", "AllCards/cover.png");
                x.setAttribute("id", "r"+j);
                x.setAttribute("width", "auto");
                x.setAttribute("height", "auto");
                x.setAttribute("alt", "one");
                //alert("c"+i);

                //alert("r"+j+" c"+i);

                document.getElementById("c"+i).appendChild(x);
                document.getElementById("r"+j).style.position = "relative";

                document.getElementById("r"+j).style.top="-80px";

                //alert("r"+j);

                }

                /*else if(j<4){
                var x = document.createElement("IMG");
                x.setAttribute("src", "AllCards/cvr.png");
                x.setAttribute("width", "auto");
                x.setAttribute("height", "auto");
                x.setAttribute("alt", "one");
                //document.getElementById("c"+i).style.position = "relative";
                //document.getElementById("c"+i).style.top="-20px";
                document.getElementById("c"+i).appendChild(x);
                }
                else if(j<5){
                var x = document.createElement("IMG");
                x.setAttribute("src", "AllCards/cvr.png");
                x.setAttribute("width", "auto");
                x.setAttribute("height", "auto");
                x.setAttribute("alt", "one");
                //document.getElementById("c"+i).style.position = "relative";
                //document.getElementById("c"+i).style.top="-20px";
                document.getElementById("c"+i).appendChild(x);
                }
                else if(j<6){
                var x = document.createElement("IMG");
                x.setAttribute("src", "AllCards/cvr.png");
                x.setAttribute("width", "auto");
                x.setAttribute("height", "auto");
                x.setAttribute("alt", "one");
                //document.getElementById("c"+i).style.position = "relative";
                //document.getElementById("c"+i).style.top="-20px";
                document.getElementById("c"+i).appendChild(x);
                }
                else if(j<7){
                var x = document.createElement("IMG");
                x.setAttribute("src", "AllCards/cvr.png");
                x.setAttribute("width", "auto");
                x.setAttribute("height", "auto");
                x.setAttribute("alt", "one");
                //document.getElementById("c"+i).style.position = "relative";
                //document.getElementById("c"+i).style.top="-20px";
                document.getElementById("c"+i).appendChild(x);
                }
                else if(j<8){
                var x = document.createElement("IMG");
                x.setAttribute("src", "AllCards/cvr.png");
                x.setAttribute("width", "auto");
                x.setAttribute("height", "auto");
                x.setAttribute("alt", "one");
                //document.getElementById("c"+i).style.position = "relative";
                //document.getElementById("c"+i).style.top="-20px";
                document.getElementById("c"+i).appendChild(x);
                }
                */


            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered setting a css class as an attribute and putting your positioning detail into that? e.g.

```
x.setAttribute("class", "rClass");
```

css:

```
.rClass {
   top:-80px;
   position:relative;
}
```

Comment: above problem is solved .....now I want is in first row alll Div should fill cards ..but in second row  , except 1st all should be filled .....in third row except first two  div all should be filled... How to write  "for loop" to get this effect ?